# HTTP OPTIONS Request: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, http-verbs

Whenever I try to fire a request with the HTTP-verb `OPTIONS` I get the following error message in the client, but no error messages on the server

`org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond`

`curl -X OPTIONS URL`gives me: `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

All other http-verbs are working fine.

The request even doesn't reach the index.php

Putting

`<Limit GET OPTIONS PUT HEAD PATCH DELETE GET>

    Order allow,deny

    Allow from all

</Limit>`

to .htaccess or vhost-config doesn't help either.

The apache server (Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)) is running in a vagrant-box (vagrant 1.3.5) built with puphet.

Clients used:

- PHPStorm - Test RESTfull Webservie
- Chrome - Dev HTTP Client

Going mad with that, as I have to answer OPTIONS-request from a backbone frontend!

Thx in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem.  Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: No, not realy.
My colleague is using the same vagrant box and not suffering this issue.
Problem disapeared after setting everything up on a new computer.